# GROUP_CONCAT automatically add double quotes only when the field contains double quotes

Tags: google-bigquery

When I use GROUP_CONCAT in BigQuery for fields that contains double quotes,
the result values are 
automatically escaped and added some double quotes.
But if the fields doesn't contain double quotes, GROUP_CONCAT behaves a little different.

#### Case1 (with double quotes)

Table

```
Row | word  | num
--- | ----  | ---
 1  | fo"o  |   1
 2  | ba"r  |   1
 3  | ba"z  |   2
```

and the Query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word) AS words, num
FROM Table
GROUP BY num
```

the results

```
Row | words         | num
--- | ------------- | ---
 1  | "fo""o,ba""r" |   1
 2  | "ba""z"       |   2
```

↑It's escaped automatically.

#### Case2 (without double quotes)

Table

```
Row | word | num
--- | ---- | ---
 1  | fo'o |   1
 2  | ba'r |   1
 3  | ba'z |   2
```

and the Query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word) AS words, num
FROM Table
GROUP BY num
```

the results

```
Row | words     | num
--- | --------- | ---
 1  | fo'o,ba'r |   1
 2  | ba'z      |   2
```

↑No double quotes added.

#### Case3(normal CONCAT with double quotes)

※The normal CONCAT doesn't behave like GROP_CONCAT.
Escaping double quotes are not added.

Table

```
Row | word  
--- | ----  
 1  | fo"o  
 2  | ba'r
```

and the Query

```
SELECT CONCAT(word, '12"3') AS words
FROM Table
```

the results

```
Row | words        
--- | ---------
 1  | fo"o12"3
 2  | ba'r12"3
```

#### Question

I wonder why the results are different between these cases.
I don't want to escape and add double quotes when Case1.
Are there any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: This is odd behavior.  Can you replace the double quotes with another character, such as '~', before the concatenation and then re-replace them afterwards?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  
I changed double quotes in each word to some other characters, such as ':', '~', '-', '¥', and retried GROUP_CONCAT.  
Then, the results are same as single quote case.
Escaping double quotes are added only when word include double quotes.

Comment: I have reported the issue to Google

Comment: @Marilu Thanks a lot. If you could get some answer from Google, I would appreciate it if you could write here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Marilu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27930257/346561), Google mentioned plans to support this use-case but didn't provide an ETA in the [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=210) at the time of posting. As of February 2015, the issue has been "Fixed".

Google has added a `GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED` function which behaves nearly identically to `GROUP_CONCAT` except for it doesn't escape the double quotes.

Here is the description of the function from the [Google Docs for BigQuery Aggregate Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=en#aggfunctions):

> `GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED('str' [, separator])`
>
> Concatenates multiple strings into a single string, where each value is separated by the optional `separator` parameter. If `separator` is omitted, BigQuery returns a comma-separated string.
>
> Unlike `GROUP_CONCAT`, this function will not add double quotes to returned values that include a double quote character. For example, the string `a"b` would return as `a"b`.
>
> **Example:** `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(x) FROM (SELECT 'a"b' AS x), (SELECT 'cd' AS x);`

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been reported to Google, however they don't provide an ETA of when this will be address.

The issue has been posted int the [Official Google BigQuery issue and feature request tracker,](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=210) updates about this matter can be found at the link provided.